# Python Merge .xls Files

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have a folder full of Excel files. One annoying aspect is that they are all `.xls` (and not `.xlsx`).

What I need to do is read in each of the `.xls` files, delete the first 7 rows, then take the remaining document and add it to a "master.xlsx" file. (note: master.xlsx doesn't have to be preexisting, can be newly created)

I haven't started trying to remove rows yet, just trying to simply merge them, but can't figure out how. Do I need to somehow convert all .xls to .xlsx first, then try to merge? I've spent hours looking at other Stack Overflow questions and online resources. It seems like some kind of ancient technology. Also, it's worth mentioning I'm using Python3.

Here's my code so far:

```
import os
from numpy import genfromtxt
import re
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd


# script directory
script_dir = os.path.dirname(r'C:/Users/Kenny/Desktop/pythonReports/')


# get array list of files
files = []
file_abs_path = script_dir + '/excels/'
for file in os.listdir(file_abs_path):
    if file.endswith('.xls'):
        excel_file_path = script_dir + '/excels/' + file
        files.append(excel_file_path)

# f is full file path
df_array = []
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('master.xlsx')
for f in files:
    sheet = pd.read_html(f)

    for n, df in enumerate(sheet):
        df_array.append(df)
        # df = df.append(df)
    # df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n)
print(df_array)

for df in df_array:
        # new_df = new_df.append(df)
        new_df = pd.concat(df_array)
        new_df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n)
        writer.save()
    # print(sheet)
```

At some point I didn't get errors and it was reading and copying the content correctly, but it would re-write the `master.xlsx` and overwrite the old stuff, instead of concatenating it.

***EDIT***

Merge is working now. My difficulty now is that I need to grab data from a cell, delete the first 7 rows, then create a new column and add that data to all rows in that column (for the length of the document).

I think that one thing that makes this hard is I have to use `read_html()` because `read_excel()` doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 83, in <module>
    sheet = pd.read_excel(f)
  File "C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 200, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 257, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 441, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 91, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1230, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1224, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n<html>\n'
```

Comment: you probably want `new_df = pd.concat(df_array)` iirc... you are simply assigning `new_df` to `df` over and over again...

Comment: Agree with Corley,` pd.concat(df)` isn't merging anything at all but gives you only the frame you hand it.    But doesn't `pd.read_excel` handle xls files as well?

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and helps a lot! I think I'm on the right track. I can now add the the end of the file the new data. Now I think I need to discover the removing of the first 7 rows in each before adding to the array. Will update question with latest code.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with pandas, but this sounds like a relatively straightforward task to do using the underlying libraries directly (xlrd for reading, XlsxWriter for writing). However, that error does seem to indicate that your input files are not true .xls files, but rather HTML files that were purposely *named* as .xls. As such, I don't understand why you said you could merge successfully. Wouldn't the data have to have been successfully read in by pandas (by whatever means) in the first place?

Comment: I figured it out, I'll post answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my final solution for merging (with a nice little dynamically changing print statement too):

```
# Merge all .xlsx files into one 'master.xlsx'

files = get_files('/xlsx/', '.xlsx')
df_array = []
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('master.xlsx')

for i, f in enumerate(files, start=1):
    sheet = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(sheet, ignore_index=True)

    # progress of entire list
    if i <= len(files):
        print('\r{:*^7}{:.0f}%'.format('Merging: ', i/len(files)*100), end='')

all_data.to_excel(writer, 'sheet')
writer.save()
```